# Keyboard Shortcut Toggle Switch

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard

I wanted to know if I can create a keyboard shortcut which toggles a function ON/OFF every time I press it. My function is xcalib (the screen gamma control programme), at night time, I often like to run `xcalib -co 40 -i -a`. I can assign it to a shortcut however I cannot find a way to be able to press it again and it reverts it, in this case, `xcalib -c`.

Comment: If you can provide the test to see what is the current state from cli, it's done in two minutes ±'

Answer (score 2):

If there is no way to find out from `xcalib` what your current setting is, you can create a helper file.

Put the following into a script, make it executable and assign a keyboard shortcut.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f ~/.night_time ]; then
    xcalib -c
    rm ~/.night_time
else
    xcalib -co 40 -i -a
    touch ~/.night_time
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought of too.

Comment: OK, although I personally would do it with `exec` call, which removes the need for creating `~/.night_time`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code, could you explain how I maybe able to perform that above code with exec thereby avoid creating that file ..out of interest..thank you